# How to make Gallery Items top aligned?

Tags: android, gallery

I have Gallery widget that displays layouts that are say 50dp high. When the user clicks on a gallery item, that layout will grow to be 100dp high. I've got this expanding behavior on touch to work fine. However, the problem is that the gallery is rendering the item as centered horizontally and vertically.

What I would like is to have it centered horizontally and top aligned. So when the user clicks on an item, it has a look of opening "rolling down".

Answer (score 1):

```
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView

           ..........
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           ..........
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```